# Using Redis as Elevation Query Service

Tags: redis, postgis, gdal

Currently I am using PostGIS to query SRTM elevation data, but I am finding that the database is extremely slow (it can take up to 100ms for a single elevation query!). I've highlighted my querying results in [Slow Elevation Batch Queries in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220164/slow-elevation-batch-queries-in-postgis) in the GIS stackexchange. As a result I am looking at switching to Redis cluster to store all of my SRTM elevation data in-memory. The SRTM data has billions of points for the entire earth, and I am curious how Redis would perform under these circumstances. Is Redis even the right tool? Should I look into grouping my points into sets to reduce the number of key/value pairs? Or Should I look into something like MongoDB? Performance and scalability are my main concerns.

Comment: Assuming you can fit it in RAM, it'll perform fine.

Comment: I'll need a cluster to fit it into RAM. The entire raster dataset is on the order of terabytes.